# Pythons 2.7.x docs about Unicode and why this still works?

Tags: python, string, unicode, 8-bit

According to the Python 2.7.x documentation:

> The `unicode()` constructor has the signature `unicode(string[, encoding, errors])`. All of its arguments should be 8-bit strings. The first argument is converted to Unicode using the specified encoding; if you leave off the encoding argument, the ASCII encoding is used for the conversion, **so characters greater than 127 will be treated as errors:**
>
> ```
>    >>> unicode('abcdef' + chr(255))    
>    Traceback (most recent call last):
>    ...
>    UnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xff in position 6:
>    ordinal not in range(128)
> ```

So why does this work with Japanese characters in it?:

```
TestStr = "サーバ移設"
print TestStr
サーバ移設
```

and why does this work too?:

```
TestStr = unicode("サーバ移設")
print TestStr
サーバ移設
```

I would have expected an unicode decode error since the Japanese characters are not within the 8bit string range.

Comment: The encoding of your text file matters.

Comment: Do you have a codec specified at the top of your file?

Comment: Your second example throws a unicode error for me, btw. Did you set `sys.defaultencoding` somewhere?

Comment: More or less, I have encoding set to UTF-8 in the site.py file. I also have the encoding UTF-8 inside the Python code. However the latter does not make a difference since I believe that it is to be able to display Python code with strings in it that contain characters above the 128 (ASCII value).

Comment: @delnan Yes I have # -*- coding: utf-8 -*- enabled inside the Python script.

Comment: @Martijn It is strange that you get (as expected an error on the second one but it is also strange that you do NOT get an error on the third one. Due to the fact I don't see any errors in example 2 and 3 I believe that I do not understand something and afraid to make a stupid coding decision.

Comment: We are talking about Python 2.7.x right?

Comment: Update...... when I change the site.py encoding back to  **ascii** then I get an error on the second example. So that seems to be in line with what I read and understand. Now why does the first example still works (with or without encoding and with or without utf-8 encoding in site.py)?

Comment: You are defining a byte string, which is not decoded. If you terminal encoding happens to match the file encoding, then it works and you see the same characters.